# How to get actual frame size of text rendered in TextView Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm using a TextView in android, as attached in snapshot, you can see on the right side text rendered with some space left in each line.

Actually my frame width is equal to the full screen width but text gets wrapped without getting rendered fully on a line leaving spaces.

What I really need is the actual frame size of the text rendered that excludes these blank spaces at end of each line. 
I hope it clears myself and let me know if you still understands situation. Appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you:

```
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(textView.getText().toString(), 0,
                textView.length(), bounds);
```

no in `bounds rect` you have the text size that been drawn.

Comment: I tried but its giving me the width/height of the whole text. Actually I need the area where text has been rendered skipping those spaces. how can i calculate that?